# Calculating Max distance from TX to RX that satifies SNR

Tags: communication, distance

I have two question, but they are both alike.

1) I am given a problem, with the following parameter:
B=20MHz, fc=2.4GHz, Ptx=26dbm,Gtx=15dBi, Grx=6dbi, receiver noise figure 5db.
and asked to find max distance bw tx and rx that satisfies SNR at receiver to equal or exceed 15dB. Assume free space propagation

I know If I am able to find the power at the receiver than I can find d

- Prx= Ptx*Gtx *Grx (λ /4πd)^2

The only problem is I have not been able to find one single example that illustrates about how to find Prx with my given parameters. I know I am given enough info to calculate N= kTB.

2) I am given roughly the same parameters only this time I know d. Is there any equations one can use to find the min transmitted power?

Comment: What power in dbm is 5dB over the thermal noise in a 20MHz bandwidth? Oh and the Friis equation is probably the one you want for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full example:

-174dBm/rtHz is the KT thermal floor

+73dB          for 10*log10(20MHz)

+5dB          receiver noise figure

+15dB          SNR for decent BER

Total these, for energy out of the RX antenna: -174 + 93 = -81dBm

Powergain:26dBm + 15 + 6 = 47dBm erp

Allowable PathLoss is -81 to +47 = 128dB pathloss

PathLoss is 22dB + 10*log10([distance/wavelength]^2), thus we have 106dB for (d/l)^2, or 53 dB for distance/wavelength, or 2 * 10^5 wavelengths

Comment: thank you, by any chance do you happen to known of any sites or doc where it talks about acquiring power of Rx like you illustrated?

Comment: Lets look at how NASA receives image-data from NewHorizons satellite, after it passed Pluto: NASA uses a cooled front end, atop their 70meter dishes; the effective temperature is 20 degrees Kelvin; the -174dBm is based on 290degree Kelvin. By reducing the temperature over 10:1, the sqrt(4KTBR) noise voltage drops 3.16:1 and the Noise Power drops 10:1

Comment: That 10:1 drop in power makes the KT thermal floor be -184dBm/rtHertz. But NASA only succeeds in 100bit/second rates, because of extreme pathloss. http://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html

Comment: Pluto is 8Billion KM distance. The carrier into Goldstone's dish is 9GHz, or 3cm. Thus the distance/wavelength is 8Billion KM/0.03meter, or 8Trillion meter/0.03, = 240Trillion. Log10 of that is (1.0 - 0.6)+log10(10^15) = 0.4 + 15 = 15.4. We must square(distance/wavelength) or double 15.4 to 30.8; we also must scale up by 10, to get dB====308dB. And we add 22dB, (4*pi)^2producing 330dB path loss.

Answer (score 0):

> The only problem is I have not been able to find one single example
>   that illustrates about how to find Prx with my given parameters

The generally accepted figure for minimum rx power is based on bandwidth thus: -

Prx = (-154 + 10log\$_{10}\$(bit rate)) dBm

Formula taken from page 15 of [**this**](http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/zhejaz/EE%20423/Book_Cambridge_Essentials%20of%20Radio%20W%20Propag_ED_2008.pdf) document (essentials of radio wave propagation).

So, for a bandwidth of 20 MHz, Prx(min) = -81 dBm

In the above I have assumed that the channel BW is equal to the bit rate.

You then have to take account of the 5 dB noise figure and the SNR.

See also [**this**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_detectable_signal) wiki page for a different version of the formula

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Lets examine a datalink across the USA, at 10 bits per second. At 50MHz. Assume vertical-whips at Transmitter and Receiver, thus gain ~~0dB.

First, what is the pathloss? Wavelength is 300/50 = 6 meters. Pathloss is 22dB + 10*log10[(distance/wavelength)^2] = 22dB + 10*log10(6,000 KM/6meter)^2]
PL = 22dB + 10*log10[ (6Million meters/6meters)*2] =22 +120 = 142dB.

Second, what signal level into the receiver front-end LowNoiseAmplifier?

-174dBm/rtHz       Boltzmann/Nyquist/Johnson/thermalfloor for 1Hz, 17 degree C

10dB             10Hz bandwidth (depends on type of modulation and coding)

5dB             NoiseFigure and matching to antenna

15dB             necessary SNR if you use no error correction

total energy into receiver: -174 + 10+5+15 = -144dBm
This is 24 dB below -120dBm(0.632uVpp), thus need 0.632/25 = 25nanoVolts.

Third, what energy from transmitter? Assuming line-of-sight over 6,000 KM.
Add PL to Receiver_front_end_input = 142dB + (-144dBm) = -2dBm or 0.5 milliWatt.

With 0.5milliWatt across 50 ohms being 400 milliVolts PP, any Smart Phone can generate this.

The challenge is to achieve low phase noise and high receiver blocking.

EDIT To handle blocking, you operate an LNA with 1 volt emitter degeneration.
To avoid serious noise problems, keep that linearizing resistor at 100_ohms or lower. The resistor gets no bypassing. With 1 volt linearization, the IP2 and IP3 (they are different numbers) will be about +10 to +15 dBv; dBv is close to dBm, for 50 ohm systems.

Now about that phasenoise: you must implement phase-tracking as part of the Receiver signal processing. Synchronous-demodulation, given a quality PLL tracking circuit, solves many problems. Signetics/Philips makes some ICs.